# Is it possible to add to a class for example a premade Java class without overriding it?

Tags: java

I was wondering if it was possible to add to another class without physically changing that particular class for example the Jbutton class as you can't edit it. Is this possible? If so does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Sorry, For me your question is not clear enough. If you can please add some example that you have tried out so far.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Take a look at the [facade pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern).  Since the question has been marked as a duplicate, I can't provide an example.